# How to add MenuItem elements with ListItemIcon's from array.map

Tags: material-ui

I'm using material-ui-next (material-ui@1.0.0-beta.38).

I try to define my applications menu with an array that contains an icon and a text (and some more data in my real application).

If I just use the jsx tags directly it works fine:

```
<div>
  <MenuItem button>
    <ListItemIcon>
      <SettingsIcon />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary="Settings 2" />
  </MenuItem>
</div>
```

But if I instead define as an array:

```
const menuItems1 = [
  { 
      icon: SettingsIcon,
      text: 'Settings 1'
  }]
```

and try to iterate over this it fails:

```
<div>
  {menuItems.map((mItem, index) => (
  <MenuItem key={mItem.key} to={mItem.path} button>
  <ListItemIcon>
    {mItem.icon}
  </ListItemIcon>
  <ListItemText primary={mItem.text} />
  </MenuItem>
))}
</div>
```

I get the error messages:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined
    at ListItemIcon (ListItemIcon.js:57)
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `function` supplied to `ListItemIcon`, expected a single ReactElement.
```

How can I get this to work by having the icon and the text defined in the array and iterating over this to add the components?

Full code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {ListItemIcon, ListItemText } from 'material-ui/List';
import { MenuItem} from 'material-ui/Menu';
import HelpIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Help';
import SettingsIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Settings';
import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider';


const menuItems1 = [
  { 
      icon: SettingsIcon,
      text: 'Settings 1'
  },
  { 
      icon: HelpIcon,
      text: 'Help 1'
  }
]
const menuItems2 = [
      { 
          icon: () => <SettingsIcon/>,
          text: 'Settings 1'
      },
      { 
          icon: () => <HelpIcon/>,
          text: 'Help 1'
      }
    ]
const menuItems3 = [
      { 
          icon: {SettingsIcon},
          text: 'Settings 1'
      },
      { 
          icon: {HelpIcon},
          text: 'Help 1'
      }
    ]

//I've tried different versions of the array, I can get any of them to work.
const menuItems=menuItems1;

class MenuTest extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
<div>
The {menuItems.length} new menu items wont work with the icons:
{menuItems.map((mItem, index) => (
        <MenuItem key={mItem.key} to={mItem.path} button>
        <ListItemIcon>
        {mItem.icon}
        </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary={mItem.text} />
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
<Divider/>
The old menu items work, but I want to have these in an Array instead:
<MenuItem button>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <SettingsIcon />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary="Settings 2" />
    </MenuItem>
<MenuItem button>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <HelpIcon />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary="Help 2" />
    </MenuItem>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MenuTest;
```

Comment: Where do you get mItem.key and mItem.path?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your menuItems should store the icon as a component :

```
const menuItems1 = [
  { 
      icon: (<SettingsIcon/>),
      text: 'Settings 1'
  },
  { 
      icon: (<HelpIcon/>),
      text: 'Help 1'
  }
]
```